# Updating link_to with a ruby on rails parameter using a select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My new school program path requires a school passed to it to denote which school is getting a new program. If there is no such school to pass, I added a dropdown that has all of the schools available so that someone can choose which school they want to add a program in. When this is selected, a javascript function triggers which adjusts the href of the button to the school value, however it is not working as I'd hoped. Here is the code:

```html
<% if can? :create, @program %>
  <%= link_to 'New Program', new_school_program_path(@new_program_school), class: 'btn btn-primary', id: 'new-program-no-school' %>
  <%= select_tag(:menu_select, options_for_select(School.pluck(:name), School.all)) %>
  <br/>
<% end %>


<script>
  $('#menu_select').bind('change', function() { 
    var newLink = $('#menu_select').val();
    $('#new-program-no-school').attr('href', '<%= new_school_program_path(newLink) %>');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem here is that Rails is rendering the javascript which is then executing independent of the Ruby code in the browser. The `newLink` variable is not available to Rails when it is rendering the path in the template.

You can do this to workaround that:

```
<script>
  $('#menu_select').bind('change', function() {
    var templatePath = '<%= new_school_program_path("school_id") %>'
    var newLink = $('#menu_select').val();
    $('#new-program-no-school').attr('href', templatePath.replace("school_id", newLink));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This worked - just had to add a slugify function to get rid of the spaces in newLink - thanks!
`function slugify(text)
  {
    return text.toString().toLowerCase()
      .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
      .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
      .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
      .replace(/^-+/, '')             // Trim - from start of text
      .replace(/-+$/, '');            // Trim - from end of text
  }`